# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not fetch initial value for increment generator

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss

In my application, I am using two hibernate.cfg.xml files to communicate the same mysql database. The hibernate cfg files are  hibernate.cfg.xml and dynamic-hibernate.cfg.xml and I am deployed my application in JBoss server.

At some time I got the exception as **"org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not fetch initial value for increment generator"** while inserting the data by using Dynamic-hibernate session. But i am not facing the problem in another Hibernate-cfg.xml session. I have also extended MYsql waittimeout. Still i'm facing the same problem

Please Help me to solve this issue.

My Dynamic-hibernate-cfg.xml :

```
<session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.default_entity_mode">dynamic-map</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping file="./WEB-INF/xml/DynamicMapping.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
```

My Another Hibernate-cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
        <mapping resource="HibernateMapping.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
```

My Exception is :

```
  org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not fetch initial value for increment generator
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator.getNext(IncrementGenerator.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator.generate(IncrementGenerator.java:44)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:557)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:545)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Connection was closed due to the following exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.sql.SQLException
MESSAGE: Communication link failure: java.io.EOFException, underlying cause: null

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1394)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1538)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1929)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the exception care fully, it is saying connection is already closed. Check in your code where the connection is closed. And also check the file is reading properly or not.